# Changing the "Show the most used apps" to "On" through Registry/GPO

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, group-policy, start-menu

Environment: Windows 10 Enterprise 1803

I am aware that the "Show the most used apps" can be controlled through the "Start Settings", however, I am interested in setting this through registry/GPO.

My eventual goal is to have freshly imaged machines have this setting set to "On" at first login and giving them the option to turn it off as required (hence the hope to deploy a One-Time Registry through Group Policy Preference).

I have tried setting registry keys to control this however the only thing I can control is if this key is greyed out or not.

Is anyone aware of a way not to use the User Interface to set the "Show the most used apps" start menu setting?

**Update**

I have tried the registry keys provided below and am not able to control this via a registry key. After some further searching I came across a Reddit post with a user that was having the same issue. He has a Microsoft Premier Support case open which was going to be one of my next steps.

Linking [Reddit post here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/912wtv/windows_10_registry_or_group_policy_setting/e3c81eo/?context=3) for historical reference. I will update SuperUser post if a resolution is found.

Comment: If you are not turning this feature off during the imaging process it is on by default and hence you don't need to try any registry or gpo hack

Comment: @Biswapriyo Thanks, Changing this setting seems to have no impact on the the setting or behaviour of start menu

Comment: @pun Just for clarification, I stood up a new virtual machine today from Vanilla Windows 10 1803 ISO. 

With no customisation made to the machine the default status of the "Show most used apps" is "Off"

Answer (score 1):

According to my knowledge, there is no such group policy or register setting. The most used app is related to what used recently, and you can only delete the app from the list.

I think that you can disable the most used app list and pin those app you want to the menu.

I will continue research and test, in order to find out if there is any solution or workaround.

---

Update.

Try the following register.

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced**
Find the key **Start_TrackProgs** and double-click on it, if it doesn't exist, just create it.
Name **Start_TrackProgs**
Type  **DWORD (32-bit)**
Data value 0  (0 uncheck, 1 check)

Re-open the **Setting**, and the option will be changed.

[image]

Hope it can help you!

Comment: Thanks otto, i am happy with the default behaviour of the Recent Apps once it is enabled it is just about getting it enabled for all users by default.

Comment: I COULD misunderstand what your point. PLease wait!.

Comment: @AndrewN. you can use this register with gpp to apply it to all the domain.

Comment: No I have just take a test.

Comment: Hi Otto,

 I should have put this in my original question. I have already tried setting the "Start_TrackProgs" Registry key however i find that all this does is greys out the "Show Most Used Apps" setting. it does not change the value from "On" to "Off"

Comment: I tested this yesterday, it worked perfectly. When I changed the register value, the on/off changed, too.

Comment: something could be mistaken.

Comment: @ottowang - based of your and Pun's findings that this should already be set by default i am going to build a VM straight from ISO to ensure no weird customisation are getting in the way.

Answer (score 0):

The registry entry behind the setting "Show most used apps" (in Personalization\Start) is this one:

> Named value: Data
>
> Key: HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CloudStore\Store\Cache\DefaultAccount\$de${be556088-c76f-41bd-809c-ba7ab5f4c3fa}$$windows.data.unifiedtile.startglobalproperties\Current
>
> Data type: REG_BINARY

You can toggle the setting by editing the named value, and it helps to copy/paste the value since you can't really interpret it. To explain: I disable the setting from the GUI, go into the registry, and copy the named value somewhere for reference; then I enable it from the GUI, go back to the registry, and copy *that* named value to my reference as well. From that point, you can use the corresponding values to disable or enable the setting via editing the registry.

Since it's very hard to understand how this value is composed, it's practically useless for administration; I hope Microsoft changes this sooner than later. There should be a decent and dedicated registry named value behind the setting and there should be a GP policy for it too (analogous to the "Show recently added apps" setting for example).

Ciao!

Comment: (1) I’m finding your text a little hard to understand. It might be clearer if you showed the values that you’re talking about.  (2) If you discuss this issue on your blog, please link to the specific page and state ***explicitly*** that it is your blog. If you’re just including it as part of your signature; don’t. We don’t allow signatures in posts. You may promote your blog on [your profile page](https://superuser.com/users/1055713/padre-pedro).

Comment: Hi Scott, I'm sorry for mentioning my blog site in my signature. I wasn't aware this was not allowed on Super User. Also, you said "It might be clearer if you showed the values that you’re talking about.". Well, the reason I haven't done this is because there are no predictable values here, they are composed dynamically. On a certain system one can obtain the right values though (the values stay the same on a certain system, so they only differ from system to system) and I have explained how to do this (i.e. setting through the Settings app and checking in the registry which value is used).